# What is the proper way to pass TProps to withApollo HOC?

Tags: react-native, flowtype, react-apollo, flow-typed

**My Problem:**I'm struggling with something that I would have thought would be quite simple: I have a react-native project where I'm using react-apollo, flow and flow-typed, and am running into an issue satisfying flow with the way I'm using the withApollo HOC. The flow error I'm getting is:

```
Missing type annotation for TProps. TProps is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly
instantiated at call of withApollo [2].
```

**My question:** I'm wondering how I should pass TProps to withApollo... what is the correct/best way to do this?

**Background:**
In my file, I have the proptypes for my component declared:

```
type type ListCollaboratorsProps = {
  ...
};
```

I use `ListCollaboratorsProps` when creating my component:

```
class ListCollaborators extends React.Component<ListCollaboratorsProps, ListCollaboratorsState> {
```

and I export my component after wrapping it in withAPollo:

```
export default withApollo(ListCollaborators);
```

After seeing the flow error, I have tried the following:

```
export default withApollo<ListCollaboratorsProps>(MyApolloComponent);
```

which seems to make flow happy... but then I get this error when trying to run my app in the simulator:

```
Can't find variable: ListCollaboratorsProps
```

which I'm confused about, since I can use `ListCollaboratorsProps` just fine when declaring my component...